# buffer manipulation in perl

Tags: perl, network-programming

I am receiving a packet over the network using perl recv call. I am able to receive the packet but the packet is formatted in such a way that first two bytes of the packet convey information about rest of the message. I do not have a lot of programming experience in perl and I am stuck that how can I copy the first two bytes from the received packet into a different variable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want [`unpack`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/unpack.html):

```
my ($byte1, $byte2) =  unpack('(a1)2', $packet);
```